# systemd condition on "location"

Tags: systemd

I have a laptop. When I work from home, I establish an ssh-tunnel to certain servers. The tunnel is realized as a systemd service which starts automatically and also restarts on failure.

At the moment, the tunnel is also established when I take my laptop to the office. Is there a way to condition the start of my tunnel service based on where I am? The location could be based on my IP address, or if it is possible to ping a certain server.

What would be the best way to have a tunnel only established when I am at home and not at the office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conditions%20and%20Asserts) defines a large number of conditions and asserts.

I would probably run two `systemd` units:

1. A `Type=oneshot` which runs a script and then generates a file based on the result.  Your script may check the SSID, default route, ip address, or something else that makes sense.
2. Your main tunnel service which has a `Condition...=` based on that file and an `After=` relationship.

For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Checking for ssid

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=-/bin/bash -c "touch %t/$(/usr/sbin/iwgetid -r).ssid"
```

Then

```
[Unit]
Description=VPN Tunnel
After=ssid.service
ConditionPathExists=%t/AtHome.ssid

[Service]
...
```

Note that `Condition...=` checks only run on startup.  So it'll only work if your machine is booted at the location.  I put the file in `%t` as that is always cleaned on reboot.

If you want this to work without a reboot, you'd need some sort of a timer which polls the first condition and starts a conflicting service if the file doesn't exist.  That would stop your tunneling service.

---

A simpler solution could also be as simple as using `ExecStartPre=` and `Restart=on-failure`

```
[Unit]
Description=VPN Tunnel

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "test $(/usr/sbin/iwgetid -r) = MyHome"
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2m
...
```

That will check that the SSID matches "MyHome".  If successful, it will run the rest of the service.  If it fails, it'll try again after `RestartSec=` (default 100ms, but that's too fast so I set it to 5m here) .

You mentioned that your current solution already restarts on failure so this might contaminate that solution, meaning your first solution may be better.  Also, `systemctl status` will show your system is degraded if you are not on your home wifi.